# How to Recover Microsoft Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, data-recovery

I'm using Microsoft Word 2010 and I worked in a word-2003 compatible document (`.doc`). After hours of working, I selected a half of text and did `Ctrl+X` to copy it into another document. Surprising, after closing the current document and opening a new one and pressing `Ctrl+V`, nothing happened. After closing original document, ms word asked me if I want to save the clipboard buffer and I pressed `No`, as I didn't knew that MS Word has it's own clipboard.

Is there a way to recover that text that was "cutten" from original document and never "pasted" to the new one? The PC was not rebooted so i guess all my temp files are here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This MAY work: On the File tab/menu, select Recent. In the lower right half is the button "Recover Unsaved Documents". Click and see if you can still recover it. This may work even after you have rebooted your computer.

You can also check the Info option on the File tab/menu - try the Manage Versions button.

FYI, every application potentially will hold the data on behalf of the clipboard. Word gives you the option of physically placing it on the clipboard when you exit Word - and that's where you should have said Yes instead of No.

Good luck,
Yosh

Answer (score 3):

To complement @yosh's answer, I had some additional issues while recovering the file, so I am posting since it might be useful to future users, in case they don't find the files using the recommended approach:

1. When my Word 2016 crashed, it didn't offer any unsaved files after restart. Clicking on the <kbd>Recover Unsaved Documents</kbd> button opened the **local** application data folder (`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\UnsavedFiles`), which was empty. But this is apparently the first folder you should try looking in, just paste the link inside Windows Explorer to check if it contains anything.
2. I then made a search of the entire `Users` folder, and found the unsaved `.asd`. files inside the **roaming** app data folder, i.e. `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\UnsavedFiles`. I am not sure why they were here, honestly. I also thought I could just rename it to `.docx`, but it didn't work (these are both `zip` files under the hood, but internal `.asd` structure seems to be different).
3. After copying the `.asd` files from roaming to the local folder, I restarted Word and then it properly showed the recovery tool window at the left side of the screen.
4. Immediately went to Word options and configured Auto recovery save interval to 2 minutes. :)

Comment: Additionally, if you told Word to remove recovery files when it asked you, you could still find the `.asd` file in the recycle bin and restore it.